# How to get list of songs from Spotipy and then save them to a txt file?

Tags: python, spotipy

I have been trying to use create a list of an artist's top 10 songs on Spotify (using Spotipy) and then save these songs to a txt file in a list but I am at a dead end with how to  do it. Sorry if it's super obvious!

Also I would love to then be able to put these songs into a playlist. I have worked out how to create a playlist, but not how to add specific songs to it, so any advice would be welcome!

My code is:

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="",
                                               client_secret="",
                                                          
redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080/"))

# shows tracks from a specific artist
choice = input("What artist's songs do you want some names of? ")

with open('songs.txt', 'r') as song_file:
    contents = song_file.read()

results = sp.search(q=[choice], limit=10)
for idx, track in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
    print(idx, track['name'])

with open('songs.txt', 'w+') as song_file:
    song_file.write(contents)

for song in contents:
    song_file.append(float(row['song']))
```

Comment: don't you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you want to append new values to file then you don't have to read `content` and write `content` again. You can open in `append mode` - `open(... 'a')`  - and `write` new values, (not `append`). But you have to convert values to string, not use float, and you may have to `write` also `'\n'` if you want values in separated lines.

Comment: you get `for song in ... ` but later you don't use `song` - why? And you use `row[...]` but you never created `row`. etc. You should have a lot of errors and you should show them in question (as text, not image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it but if you want to append new values to file then you don't have to read it and write it again. You may open it in `append mode` - `open(..., "a")` and then `write()` will add text at the end of file.

And when you get data from server then you should run `for`-loop inside `with open()` and `write` new information as text with `\n` to put in separated lines

```
results = sp.search(q=[choice], limit=10)

with open('songs.txt', 'a') as song_file: # open in `append mode`
    for idx, track in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):  # run loop inside `with open`
        #print(idx, track['name'])
        song_file.write( f'{idx} {track['name']}\n' )   # write as string and add `\n` to put in separated lines
```

Comment: Note that if you open via append mode and run the program again, it will append the same songs again to the file.